# Couldn't run MVC 3 application with 64bit business object?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, 64-bit

I am trying to convert my asp.net 64 bit application to MVC 3.

I want to reuse my model but as soon as I add my model which is compiled in 64bit to mvc project, application fails to run and I get **System.BadImageFormatException** error.

Later I found that even if I create a sample mvc 3 application and change it to 64bit. It produces the same error. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

The obvious question is, are you sure you're running your application on a 64 bit OS? And if you're running it in IIS, is it a 64 bit worker process?

Comment: I use windows 7 64 bit and my business logic(model) are compiled keeping Platform target as x64.